# signed url from s3 bucket for m3u8 extension file

Tags: amazon-s3, jwplayer, m3u8

iam not able to play s3 signed url for m3u8 file extension on jw-player but it is working for mp4 extension file.

Please can any one help me out from this problem..

here is my code

var player = jwplayer('myDiv').setup({
                    file: 'signed url from s3 bucket(m3u8 extension)',
                    "image": "thumb.jpg",
                    "height": 360,
                    "width": 640,
                });

Comment: Are you using your own S3 bucket for this? Or is your video hosted with JWPlayer? I would recommend testing the signed S3 url yourself to see if it's really working (outside of the player).

Comment: There's also this post that mentions diagnostics on the AWS side https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=483963

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, I think it is due to the paths in the m3u8 file itself. They are not signed url.

I am pretty sure I will end up doing a self generated m3u8 containing the signed urls.